# Reload namespaced constant in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ran into an interesting scenario today that I'm unsure how to resolve.

Given a rails app with an initializer:

file: `config/initializers/integrations.rb`

```
Integrations::CONFIGS = { "key" => "value" }.freeze
```

If I go into `bundle exec rails console` and ask for that constant it works as expected:

```
Integrations::CONFIGS
=> {"key"=> "value"}
```

Then if I use `reload!` in the console, I lose that constant:

```
[2] pry(main)> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Integrations::CONFIGS
NameError: uninitialized constant Integrations::CONFIGS
from (pry):3:in `<main>'
```

If I remove the namespace and just have `CONFIGS` as a constant it works and reloads as expected.  I've read through as much of the `reload!` documentation as I could find and from what I can tell this isn't expected.

My question being, how can I correctly use a namespaced constant in an initializer while also still being able to use `reload!`?

Comment: Can’t reproduce on 2.1.8/3.2. What version of Ruby / Rails do you use?

Comment: Good question - I'm on `2.3.1/3.2-stable`

Comment: OK, hence it’s Ruby glitch, not Rails. I’ll try to setup 2.3 and report back.

Comment: I am able to reproduce with ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with 2.3.1 either. Weird.

Comment: OK. Please @Anthony try to write is as `class Integrations ; CONFIGS = ... ; end` and/or just open the class `Integrations` immediately after `Integrations::CONFIGS = ...`. I believe both would do the trick.

Comment: @mudasobwa It works if I open the module, `module Integrations; CONFIGS = ...; end;`.  It doesn't load the entire module but that's a different issue.  Interesting

Comment: It clearly does not load the entire module, it probably even should not. In any case, when it comes to Rails voodoo magic, like `reload`, I never try to find a good reason on why this code works that way :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you eventually found a solution? I'm also on 2.3.1, but Rails 4.2.2. It seems that what we have in common, is we both use pry for the command line. Could that be the cause?

Comment: @bo-oz I never found a solution :(