# Rails can't find my classes after a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a custom module with a class in Rails. I put this in my autoload inside the application.rb

`config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/classes"`

The module has a reference to a file in a deeper folder:

a.rb

```
require_relative './b/b.rb'

module A

  def self.abc content
    return A::B.new
  end

end
```

B has nothing fancy:

b.rb

```
module A

  class B
    def initialize
    end
  end
end
```

What's happening right now is that in the beginning this works perfectly, but after some requests, or a certain amount of time, it stops working and I get an: `uninitialized constant A::B` error.

Any ideas? The fact that it works in the beginning is confusing me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen when you change method `abc` to `return B.new`?

Comment: Yes, it does, that was my orginal code by the way. I tried to solve this by adding the explicit namespace. I found out though that class B seems to be working everytime, but another class in file `b.rb`, called `class C` gives the uninitialized error. But this is also not consequent across multiple of these files. Something strange going on.

Comment: And in which env does this happen? Dev, Production, both?

Comment: Dev, didn't have the courage to push this to prod with these kind of issues :)

Comment: Do you use spring or added some new gems recently? Maybe something messes up autoloading?

Comment: Saw something similar -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328628/reload-namespaced-constant-in-initializer

Comment: Yes, I have enabled Spring. Could that be causing this?

Comment: @Anthony, seems to be a comparable issue indeed. No solution unfortunately... Could it be related to Pry?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? If you have `b/b.rb` and inside it `module A; Class B`, then that might be the reason. Rails expects a module that matches the directory name.

Comment: The directory is named `a`, so the class B is actually in `a/b.rb`, I think I followed the naming convention correctly. Also, Rails & console are able to find the constants the first few minutes, but somehow looses track of the autoload after a while.